# Trigger on a field to capture the value and time when it's updated

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to add a trigger on a field say F from a table ABC and insert its value in a table DEF new_field attribute and also capture the time of update in a field DEF.date using SYSDATE Function in oracle

Following is my newly created table into which i want to insert values

```
CREATE TABLE Updated_log (
  MPN_ID     NUMBER,
  Is_Updated_value   VARCHAR2(200),
  MODIFYDATE DATE
 );
```

I'm having trouble writing FOR update on a specific attribute LIST24 from page_two

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AGILE.Check_Update
    BEFORE UPDATE ON AGILE.PAGE_TWO
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Updated_log (MPN_ID, Is_Updated_value, MODIFYDATE)
   VALUES( NEW.id, NEW.LIST24, SYSDATE);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pseudorecords (`new` and `old`), when referenced in trigger body, have to be preceded with a colon sign (`:`).

Test case:

```
SQL> create table page_two (id number, list24 number);

Table created.

SQL> create table updated_log (mpn_id number, is_updated_value varchar2(20), modifydate date);

Table created.
```

Trigger; see lines #4 (pseudorecord in `when` clause doesn't (actually, must not) have colon sign) and #8 (in trigger body, there must be a colon sign):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger check_update
  2    before update on page_two
  3    for each row
  4    when (new.list24 is not null)          --> here
  5  begin
  6    insert into updated_log
  7      (mpn_id, is_updated_value, modifydate)
  8      values
  9      (:new.id, :new.list24, sysdate);     --> here
 10  end;
 11  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into page_two (id, list24) values (1, 100);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from updated_log;

no rows selected

SQL> update page_two set list24 = 200 where id = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From page_two;

        ID     LIST24
---------- ----------
         1        200

SQL> select * from updated_log;

    MPN_ID IS_UPDATED_VALUE     MODIFYDAT
---------- -------------------- ---------
         1 200                  19-JUL-23

SQL>
```